# Error while using jQuery .animate() in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code with jQuery version 1.4.4:

```
var currentMemberID = 1;
$('div[memberContainer='+currentMemberID+']').fadeOut(500, function() {                
                $(this).parent().animate({
                    height: '0px',
                    margin: '0px',
                    padding: '0px'
                }, 500, null);                
            });
```

This code works fine in Google Chrome and Firefox, but i get the following error in IE 8:

> Invalid argument" after it finish with the fadeOut operation.

The parent of the div is an `<li>`.

Any thoughts on how this error can be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround:

```
 $('div[memberContainer='+currentMemberID+']').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).parent().css('padding', '0px');
                $(this).parent().animate({
                    height: '0px',
                    margin: '0px'                    
                }, 500, null);                
            });
```

I'm now changing the padding outside of the animate and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut sets the display of the element to 'none' when it reaches 0. Perhaps IE has a problem with accessing it's parent through 'this' when display is set to 'none'.

Have you tried animating opacity instead?

```
$("#childDiv").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
    $(this).parent.animate({ height: '0px', width'0px' }, 500, null);
});
```